# zsh - How to run a script at leaf directories?

Tags: zsh, directory

I have a folder structure like this

```
|_folder1
| |_folder1.1
| | |_folder1.1.1
| |   |_img00
| |   |_...
| |_folder1.2
|   |_img00
|   |_...
|_folder2
  |_img00
  |_...
```

I want the script that combines images into pdfs to run at the leaf directories

Answer (score 4):

- [Wildcard pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) for files in [all subdirectories traversed recursively](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing): `**/*`
- To select directories only, add the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `/`: `**/*(/)`
- Unless you have the `glob_dots` option turned on, add the glob qualifier `D` to include matches that begin with a dot.
- Add the glob qualifier `N` to allow the list of matches to be empty: `**/*(/DN)`

Now that you have the list of subdirectories, to get the leaf directories only, check for each directory to see if it has no subdirectory: check if `*(/DN)` is empty. You can add the glob qualifier `Y1` to stop listing matches after the first.

```
for d in **/*(/DN); do
  sub=($d/*(/DNY1))
  if (($#sub)); then continue; fi
  process_leaf_directory $d
done
```

With most filesystems, there's an easier way: a leaf directory has a link count of 2 (only the entry for it in its parent directory and its `.` entry, whereas a non-leaf directory also has the `..` entries in its subdirectories). This makes the filtering simpler: check for a link count of 2 with the glob qualifier `l`.

```
for d in **/*(/DNl2); do
  process_leaf_directory $d
done
```

Comment: see also `()(($#)) $d/*(/DNY1) && continue` to avoid the temporary `sub` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The following `find` command would find every leaf directory under the current directory, and execute a script within it:

```
find . -type d -links 2 -execdir /path/to/script.sh some arguments here \;
```

This would execute the command given to `-execdir` in each leaf directory under the current directory.

The same, but using `zsh` (does not consider hidden names):

```
for dirpath in ./**/*(/l2); do
    ( cd "$dirpath" && /path/to/script.sh some arguments here )
done
```

The pattern `./**/*(/l2)` would expand to the pathname of any leaf directories under the current directory.  The `**` matches recursively down into directory structures while `*(/l2)` would match any name that is a directory with a link count of exactly 2 (i.e. it's a directory with no subdirectories, a fact also used by the `find` command above).

Note that on some filesystems, like Apple's APFS, directories may have a link count greater than 2 even when they have no subdirectories. On BTRFS, the link count for directories is always 1.  This solution would therefore not work on those filesystems.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: `-execdir` runs the script in the **parent** of the selected directory, not the directory itself.

Comment: That `-links 2` trick only works in some traditional Unix file systems and if no directory hard links other than `.` and `..` are ever created. It won't work on `btrfs` for instance where the link count for directories is always 1.